# A gray 'pyramid' appeared that limited my model to what was inside that 'pyramid', but only in solid and wireframe view

Tags: 3d-view

I was editing in material preview, but when I switched to solid view, most of my scene did not show, just the parts that fell into a dark rectangular pyramid.  The pyramid itself is positioned and rotated arbitrarily.

Comment: can we get a screenshot?

Comment: Could it be the *view clipping*. Press Alt B to disable view clipping.